# Is there a better way to wrap bottom sheet height for ModalBottomSheetLayout/BottomSheetScaffold

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

My solution works, but sometimes when switching between boxes using `openSheet()` height of content cannot be calculated in time and it's jumps when opens.

Working solution using `ModalBottomSheetLayout`:

```kotlin
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val density = LocalDensity.current
var topAppBarHeight = Dp.Unspecified
var sumHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(Dp.Unspecified) }

var currentSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val openSheet: (sheet: Int) -> Unit  = {
    currentSheet = it
    sumHeight = topAppBarHeight + (currentSheet * 50).dp
    scope.launch { sheetState.show() }
}
val closeSheet: () -> Unit = {
    scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }
    sumHeight = Dp.Unspecified
}

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.height(sumHeight),
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable(onClick = closeSheet)
                        .onGloballyPositioned { lc ->
                            topAppBarHeight = with(density) { lc.size.height.toDp() }
                        },
                    title = { Text("TopAppBarSheetContent") }
                )
            },
            content = {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height((currentSheet * 50).dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
            },
        )
    },
    content = {
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(title = { Text("TopAppBarContent") })
            },
            content = { innerPadding ->
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {
                    items(50) { item ->
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .clip(CircleShape)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(75.dp)
                                .background(Color.Red)
                                .clickable { openSheet(item) }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Maybe there is a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue